# Backbonejs Search Collection with Model with Object default

Tags: backbone.js, collections

I have a model like this

```
var myModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
      a: '',
      b: '',
      c: ''
  }
});
```

My collection `myCollection` gets populated with the data and the `c` value is a list of objects.

I am trying to figure out how I can lookup a value within `myCollection` such that it matches the items within my models `c` and returns that model if a match is found ?

The values in `c` are objects like

```
"c": {"1": {}, "2": {}, "3": {}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`find()`](http://underscorejs.org/#find) function, which iterates over the collection and returns the first model that matches your conditions. Something like this:

```
result = myCollection.find(function (model) {
  return model.get("c").indexOf(5) != -1;
});
```

Or use [`filter()`](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) instead of `find()`, to get *all* of the models that pass the condition.

Comment: thanks a lot for the response. will this allow me for example to search for "2" within the list of objects contained within `c` and then return that model ?

Comment: Yes, you'd replace the 2nd line with something like: `return model.get("c")["2"] !== undefined;`

Comment: thanks again - i made a fiddle with the two scenarios. still getting stuck a bit! love any help http://jsfiddle.net/M5Mse/1/

Comment: p.s - if anyone else runs into trouble. remember that any variable passed into `indexOf` from a direct `get` is required to be `indexOf(parseInt(var))`